# Swagger: minLength / maxLength properties on array items

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

## Context

Having a list of strings in my dto like this:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "A list of strings")
@JsonProperty("STRING_LIST")
private List<@Size(max = 4) String> myStringList;
```

Using the @Size(max = 4) annotation i want to restrict the strings to have a max of 4 chars.

Therefore i would expect the following in the generated swagger file:

```
"STRING_LIST" : {
   "type" : "array",
   "description" : "A list of strings",
   "items" : {
   "type" : "string",
   "minLength": 0,
   "maxLength": 50
   }
}
```

### Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

## Problem

Actually the size annotations are missing in the generated swagger file:

```
"STRING_LIST" : {
   "type" : "array",
   "description" : "A list of strings",
   "items" : {
   "type" : "string"
   }
}
```

## Question

What is the correct way to achieve this? Or is it not possible for Collections to restrict the items with swagger?

Comment: Looks like this issue [was fixed](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3255) in Springfox 3.0.